# SSRS IIF Issue expression

Tags: reporting-services, iif

Not sure what went wrong with this expression. Please help.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2") = "", "None", (Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

The error message is

> "the value expression for the textbox refer directly to the field 'ID'
>   without specifying a dataset aggregate. When the report contains
>   multiple datasets., field reference outside of a data region must be
>   contained within aggregate function which specify a data scope"

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket at the end of the expression. BTW, when asking a question, you should always say what you wanted to happen, and what actually happened. Saying that something went wrong is usually too vague for anyone to know what the problem is.

Comment: Added Closing bracket but still get error " the value expression for the textbox refer directly to the field 'ID' without specifying a dataset aggregate. When the report contains multiple datasets., field reference outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate  function which specify a data scope"